# Detecting missing resources in QT Stylesheets

Tags: qt, logging, resources, stylesheet

I am using QCSS stylesheets in QT to skin several buttons with images from the QT resource system:

```
QFrame#DialogButtonTitle_SaveAsNew
{
  background-image: url(images:DialogButtonTitle_SaveAsNew.png);
}
```

This works great, but I would really like to write a warning to our logs if the image file referenced from the CSS could not be found (and the button is thus naked). Any way to catch such errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @andref answer, I came up with this, which works for me (TM):

```
class LoggingEngineHandler : public QAbstractFileEngineHandler
{
public:
  LoggingEngineHandler()
  : QAbstractFileEngineHandler()
  , m_lookUpInProgress(false)
  , m_lookUpPaths(QRegExp("^(images|meshes|app|sounds):"))
  {
    // empty
  }

  QAbstractFileEngine* create(const QString &fileName) const override
  {
    if (!fileName.contains(m_lookUpPaths))
      return 0;

    if (m_lookUpInProgress)
      return 0;

    m_lookUpInProgress = true;
    QFileInfo info = QFileInfo(fileName);
    m_lookUpInProgress = false;

    if (!info.exists())
    {
      assert(!Utilities::isRunByUser("designer"));
      LOG_WARN("Required resource file does not exist: %1%", QUtil_s(fileName));
    }

    return 0;
  }
protected:
  mutable bool m_lookUpInProgress;

  QRegExp m_lookUpPaths;
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but why do you need the `m_lookUpInProgress`? Does the `QFileInfo` access need to be guarded?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do it like this:

- Read about the [QAbstractFileEngine](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractfileengine.html) and [QAbstractFileEngineHandler](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractfileenginehandler.html) classes.
- Extend Qt's own implementation, [QFSFileEngine](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfsfileengine.html). I believe it also handles the ":" namespace.
- Reimplement the [`QAbstractFileEngine::open()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractfileengine.html#open) method.
- Register your engine using a custom QAbstractFileEngineHandler. The `create()` method should check the file name to see if it is being read from a resource file.

Haven't tested, but I think it should work. Code:

```
bool MyEngine::open(QIODevice::OpenMode mode)
{
    bool r = QFSFileEngine::open(mode);
    if (!r) {
        qWarning() << "Failed to open" << fileName();
    }
    return r;
}

QAbstractFileEngine *MyEngineHandler::create(const QString &fileName) const
{
     return fileName.startsWith("images:") ? new MyEngine(fileName) : 0;
}
```

**Edit.**

This will not work. The resource file system, “:”, is handled by a private file engine called [QResourceFileEngine](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/corelib/io/qresource_p.h#line61), not by QFSFileEngine.

Comment: Thanks! Good solution. Will give it a spin!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that Qt will call one of their message functions when something like this happens (although I don't know for sure).  If it does, you could install a message handler function and append some or all of the messages to your log file.  There is some information about doing so in the [documentation for `qInstallMsgHandler`](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler).

Comment: I don't know... There is already a default handler in place that prints to the standard output. If no message appears on the console, Qt is probably not writing it to begin with.

Comment: Yes, the message handler does not help in this particular situation.